# What's going on here? Some kind of rationalization "under the covers"?

Tags: bugs, polynomials, version-9

Observe:

```
eq = (.25 a + .5 b + .25 c);
CoefficientRules[eq^2]
CoefficientRules[eq^2 // Expand]
```

results in

> > {{2, 0, 0} -> 1/16, {1, 1, 0} -> 1/4, {1, 0, 1} -> 1/8, {0, 2, 0} -> 
> >       1/4, {0, 1, 1} -> 1/4, {0, 0, 2} -> 1/16}

and

> > {{2, 0, 0} -> 0.0625, {1, 1, 0} -> 0.25, {1, 0, 1} -> 
> >       0.125, {0, 2, 0} -> 0.25, {0, 1, 1} -> 0.25, {0, 0, 2} -> 0.0625}

Why is the former, without expansion, giving exact results with inexact arguments?

I noted this when doing some very lengthy polynomial operations with coefficient extraction when looking at performance of exact vs machine precision, and I'm curious *why* MMA is doing this, and the performance impact therein (i.e., if it did not do this, could it be faster without the overhead of expansion, etc.).

Edit: MMA 9.x, Windoze.

Comment: Does `CoefficientArrays[]` exhibit similar behavior?

Comment: With 10.3 on Win7 64bit, I get the second output for both cases...

Comment: @YvesKlett. get same you did on OS X with V10.3

Comment: I get the same as OP, version 10.2 Linux

Comment: It's a really neat bug to play around with - how big of a rational fraction can you make it generate?  Try `eq = (.25252525252525254525252525252535252525252252545252525252525352525252525525 a + .50 b + .25 c);`

Comment: Reporting as a bug.

Comment: `CoefficientRules[( N[Pi, 1000] x + 1)^2]`   (confirmed w/10.1)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thanks for action/edits.

Comment: @J.M.Nope, CoefficientArrays works as expected.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau - would you mind adding your bug comment as answer, so question does not sit as unanswered?

Comment: @ciao Congrats on hitting `10000`!

Comment: @Artes: Thanks, was already there (IIRC near 20K) long time ago, then gave points away. Looks like time to find more to give away...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug which is under active investigation.